# How could I only print tunnels that use TCP protocol using the ngrok API in python?

Tags: python, api, ngrok

Im quite new to Python and APIs, but anyway.

Im trying to only print out the running tunnels public url that use the TCP protocol from ngrok API.
I have got it to print all my running tunnels urls, but not specific protocols.

How could i modify this code to print only the TCP protocol tunnels public urls i have running?

```
import ngrok


client = ngrok.Client("API KEY HERE")

for tunnels in client.tunnels.list():
    print(tunnels.public_url)
```

I'm using [this documentation](https://ngrok.com/docs/api#api-tunnels-list)

[And this](https://python-api.docs.ngrok.com/client.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the documentation of ngrok's python api it seams that each tunnel has it's `proto` property
https://python-api.docs.ngrok.com/datatypes.html#ngrok.datatypes.Tunnel.proto

```py
for tunnel in client.tunnels.list():
  if tunnel.proto == 'tcp':
    print(tunnel.public_url)
```